# How to activate different anaconda environment from powershell

Tags: python, powershell, command-line, anaconda, conda

I have two environments in anaconda, namely: `root`, `2env`. When I open anaconda prompt, I can switch from `root` to `2env` by typing: `activate 2env`. I also have conda in  my powershell, but when I open powershell and try to run `conda activate 2env` it gives the following error:

> CommandNotFoundError: 'activate'

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Activate is not a valid command for `conda`.  Conda is mostly used for package management. Try `conda -h` to see valid commands.  You need `activate` in your powershell.

Comment: I also typed `activate env2` but it doesn't activate the env2 environment.

Comment: So the way anaconda works is by default (an option in the install) it doesn't add itself to your `PATH` environmental variable, so the commands will not be available in your shell.  Starting the anaconda shell adds the reference to PATH.

Answer (score 65):

Although Conda previously did not support PowerShell, this is now resolved in [Conda 4.6](https://www.anaconda.com/conda-4-6-release/).

After adding `Anaconda3/Scripts/` to your PATH variable, you should be able to initialize Conda for use with powershell with:

```sh
conda init powershell
```

Afterwards, you can use `conda` normally:

```sh
conda activate base
```

Comment: It cannot activate the virtualenv.

Comment: @GoingMyWay Conda  4.6.14 is functional

Comment: If for some reason you are using a custom prompt (for something else), it gets messed up by the activate. But you can fix it, if you're good at PS profile hacking  and adding:
`if ("$env:CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER" -match "(base)") { ... }`.

Comment: @not2qubit I think that would be a valid question-answer pair which you could link to

Comment: Does `conda init powershell` need to be run from powershell, or can it be run from a command prompt?

Answer (score 8):

I found this command while using vs code `& cmd /k "activate <env> & powershell"` .
It is working

Comment: it opens in powershell but you can change envs making it useless for my usecase.

Answer (score 6):

I found this solution:

> I've been building on BCSharp's excellent work at my own repo (currently on PR).
>
> Just do: `conda install -n root -c pscondaenvs pscondaenvs`
>
> You need Conda 4.1 or above (check with conda info conda) - otherwise
>   please install the latest version.
>
> Behavior is exactly like CMD - use activate or deactivate
>   appropriately. It's completely backwards compatible and will also
>   launch both .ps1 and .bat activate.d/deactivate.d scripts.

from https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/626#issuecomment-346224990 has worked really well for me.

Comment: This no longer works with Conda 4.6, which resolves issue #626.

Answer (score 1):

I have been battling this issue for a while. I found a solution by using a batch script and calling `call activate %env%`. I hope this can help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open PowerShell.
2. Run `conda init` (not `conda init powershell` as the accepted answer suggests).
3. Close and re-open PowerShell.
4. Use conda normally.

Comment: Gives `conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Answer (score 0):

Someone may encounter some errors, like
`\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because its operation is blocked by software restriction policies`
Just execution
`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` as administrator in powershell, after that then reopen powershell the problem should be resolve.

Answer (score -5):

Here is a work around - start cmd shell .  Run - activate   .  Check - conda env list .  Start powershell - powershell .