# How to run python script including pandas via powershell

Tags: python, pandas, powershell

I have a simple python script including pandas which I want to run using powershell using `python "C:\Users\...\Test script.py"`. However, running the script in powershell results in the following error message:

```
+ python "test_function.py"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Traceback (most recent call last)::String) [], 
RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

File "test_function.py", line 1, in <module>
import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

The python script runs normally in pycharm and when I delete the part where using the pandas the script also runs via powershell. Hence, my question is how to run a python script with pandas using powershell?

Comment: How did you install Python? If you're using conda you probably need to activate the `base` environment first. You're `pandas` installation is probably in the virtual environment and the interpreter you're calling can't find it

Comment: similar question in this page, check if that helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676403/running-python-in-powershell

Comment: @AlessandroGaballo I indeed use conda to install python. Do you mean to activate `base` in powershell first? Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @bml `conda activate base` should do the job, if the conda executable is in your path

Comment: @AlessandroGaballo could you maybe elaborate a bit more on "if the conda executable is in your path"? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @bml have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800794/how-to-activate-different-anaconda-environment-from-powershell/54811138

Comment: Great it works! Thanks you so much!