# I can not import torch

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

when I tried the "import torch" ı am getting this error .How can ı fix it?
I left error as a photo
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmpwB.png)

Comment: As the other user stated, you do not have Pytorch installed. If you think you already installed it using Anaconda, know that your Anaconda environment is not activated in that powershell session. To use conda on powerhsell, this answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54811138/5594257

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory shows Anaconda 3. Try to install pytorch using the Anaconda command in the below link

https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch

Comment: When your working with Anaconda you need to install the python libraries using conda command. Everything library will be stored there and it is easy to use the Anaconda rather that installing the libraries using the pip in Windows operating system.